# Using ARRAYFORMULA to do two functions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a spreadsheet like this:

```
4.5
5.0
4.5
5.1
5.1
4.5
```

And I want to achieve a range like this:

```
4.5 | 3
5.0 | 1
5.1 | 2
```

I can achieve this with two formulas `UNIQUE` and `COUNTIF`, but - as far as I know - that requires me to have something like this:

```
=UNIQUE | =COUNTIF
        | =COUNTIF
        | =COUNTIF
        | =COUNTIF
        | ...
```

How could I condense this down? I know `ARRAYFORMULA` is probably in the right ballpark, but I'm wondering if there's even a single-celled formula way to achieve this (eg something like `={UNIQUE,ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF)}` or some sort of notation to do two different formulas at once)

EDIT:

After a bit of messing around, I was able to condense it down to something along the lines of

```
=UNIQUE | =ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(range,FILTER(unique_range,unique_range<>"")))
```

But still wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `QUERY` formula for that

```
=QUERY(J20:J,"select J, count(J) where J is not null
                group by J label count(J) '' ",0)
```

[image]

---

**Functions used:**

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)